# Почему Servlet передает null в JSP?

Tags: java, jsp, servlet

Собственно вопрос в теме. Ниже код `Servlet` и `JSP`.

Servlet

```
import java.io.IOException;    
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;


@WebServlet("/")
public class TestServlet extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public TestServlet() {
        super();
    }

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

        request.setAttribute("name", "test");
        getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("index.jsp").forward(request, response);
    }
}
```

JSP

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" />
        <title>http</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <%
            String name = (String) request.getAttribute("name");
        %>
        <h1> Hello <%out.print(name); %> </h1>


    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: почему `String name = (String) request.getAttribute("name");` а просто `<h1> Hello ${name} </h1>` не пробовали?

Comment: А попробуйте jstl использовать, и вывод через <c:out value="${name}"/> без предварительного request.getAttribute(...);

Comment: Проблема в том, что выводит null.

Comment: @vAleksashin, у меня такая конструкция нормально работает. Вы уверены, что этот jsp именно тот, который возвращает сервлет? Попробуйте стереть внутренность jsp и запустить приложение. Нужно удостовериться, что сервлет возвращает именно этот файл.

Answer (score 0):

в JSP попробуйте так

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" />
        <title>http</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <%
     //       String name = (String) request.getAttribute("name");
String name = (String) session.getAttribute("name");
        %>
       <!-- <h1> Hello <%out.print(name); %> </h1> -->
        <h1> Hello <%=name %> </h1> 

    </body>
</html>
```